# How do I do a cross domain GET of an XML feed in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: ajax, json, wordpress, cross-domain

I would like to use AJAX to display dynamic content via my wordpress plugin. The data source is an xml feed from a remote domain (not owned by me).

I have tried using JQuery plugins that use YQL to do cross domain Ajax calls; however, they are geared towards json and tend to return the data in a mangled state.

My question is, is there a way of obtaining an xml feed using ajax from a remote domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my YQL code wasn't quote correct. I ended up making a YQL request in my javascript successfully.